# Saving strings from WPF to MySQL varchar

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, encoding, utf-8

I have an WPF application that reads data from a file like so:

```
foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(file, Encoding.UTF8))
{}
```

Each line is then parsed and displayed on the screen which all works fine. Some of the data has cyrillic alphabet in it and the strings that I'm using to store this data in are also displayed fine on the screen in the app window.

However, after that I'm using those same strings to insert them into MySQL database. I'm building a query and firing it up `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);` which successfully inserts a new line in the database with the appropriate information. Numbers are all fine, however all the strings that go into the database and have cyrillic letters are displayed as `????????`

Database engine is InnoDB and the encoding of the table and all varchar fields in it is utf_general_ci so any idea what is going on and how can I save the correct string in the database?

EDIT:
Per request, here's some code. Database connection:

```
    conn = new MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "//censored//";
```

And the file reading / db loading, shortened for the purposes of this code snippet:

```
foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(file, Encoding.UTF8))
{
      string[] tokens = line.Split('|');
      string query = "INSERT INTO myTable SET first_name = '" + tokens[0] + "'" + ", last_name = '" + tokens[1] + "'";
      MessageBox.Show(tokens[0]);
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The message box shows the name as it should be but what goes into the database is ???????.

Comment: I'm not familiar with InnoDB, but is it possible that you need `nvarchar` instead of just `varchar` fields?

Comment: There's no nvarchar datatype in MySQL, however, I don't think that this is the problem as I'm successfully able to store cyrillic characters in the same fields if I input them, let's say from the Insert functionality of PHPMyAdmin. If I insert the data from WPF though, then it goes all ???????

Comment: Can you post your full code for inserting the text? i.e. where `query` and `conn` are defined, etc?

Comment: Edited the original post with some code snippets.

Comment: I actually did figure it out. The part that I censored is the key as I have to specify there what time of encoding the connection is going to have. Default is obviously not UTF8, posting an answer below!

Comment: Also, you might want to look into parameterized sql, as it will be safe from injection attacks. As your code is now, a bad file could cause you some trouble.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now that the test application is working, it's time to do all kinds of improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some headbanging I did figure out where the problem is so posting an answer for all to see:

The key part is the way you establish your connection to the database:

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Server = YOURSERVER; Database = YOURDB; Uid = YOURUSER ; Pwd = 'YOURPASSWORD'; charset=utf8;";
```

I was missing the `charset=utf8;` part before so I assume all kinds of non-utf8 junk was going to the database regardless of the fact that I was encoding in UTF8 on both sides of the connection. Hope this helps!